# XCode-Bundle Identifier prefix confusion

Tags: ios, xcode

I am brand new to push notifications and I am having some trouble setting up my provisioning profile. The bundle id for my app is com.mycompany.myapp in my info.plist file. However, when I am creating my development provisioning profile to test push notifications the drop-down menu 'App ID:' only has an option that reads: 'PREFIX.com.mycompany.myapp' where PREFIX is 10 characters numbers and letters. When I try to add my provisioning profile to my application in the Organizer, the downloaded provisioning profile file is greyed out, which prevents me from setting up push notifications. My question is: **do I need to change the bundle identifier in my info.plist to include the prefix as shown in the 'APP ID' drop-down menu in my provisioning profile? If not, what else could be causing this problem?** Sorry about the seemingly basic question, I am new to this process and don't fully understand what needs to be accomplished. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Bundle Identifier is in Xcode Project and Provisional Profile is the same, then Provisional profile is displayed in black color. If it's not the same, then it would be greyed out.

Make Sure that the Bundle identifier which you set in while creating provisional profile should be same bundle identifier is  set in  Xcode Project.